# 2013 on-premise host named sitecollection renaming gives 404 error

Tags: 2013

I am trying to rename host named sitecollection from "xyz.domain.com.au" to xyz-uat.domain.com.au" and powershell to rename runs fine and i can get the new url with powershell as well but when i browse to the new url it shows a "404 not found" error.
[image: website error]

What do i need to do? The new url has been added into the dns records as well and i have also added it to the servers host file pointing to the server itself (for testing) but still getting the not found error.

Comment: Did you update the host name in IIS too?

Comment: @Conax Yes i did